# Can you get back to the original state of the levels?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

I'd like to play again some moons, things like when the Desert was frozen over, or New Donk City at night. They were great to play setpieces.

But do I have to play the game again from the start to see them again? or is there a way to trigger a rerun of the original state of the level?

Comment: I don't think this is possible outside of restarting the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now there is no way to do this. I've beaten the game, each world in it, and completed several (some coins, some moons, some both). There does not seem to be any hidden options or NPCs that would trigger something like this.

The only thing that fits this criteria is replaying the Festival in New Donk City, but that's only allowed because there are moons hidden in it, so this prevents you from permanently missing them.

Comment: Having pretty much 100% the game, pretty sure this is accurate.

Comment: Today I was able to replay the boss prior to the credits by returning to the location (vague since I want to avoid spoilers).

Comment: @zarose that's different from resetting the stage. The stages (new donk city, the desert, etc) are not resettable in this fashion. In fact, the boss you refer to also only resets for that instance - the level you're on does not change one bit.

Comment: @Seiyria Good point, from the point of view of the question title. I think I was commenting from the perspective that the OP wanted to "play again some moons", which would be possible if that boss was one they wanted to replay.

Comment: Or you could create a second Nintendo account, which will reset your peogress if you play on the new account